# replacing wheel studs on a 92 Buick century

Tags: buick, century, wheel-lugs

Some of my studs are crossthreaded from the last mechanic who replaced my tires and wasn't paying attention to his impact wrench.  The problem is, there is no space to get the new studs in, and I had to cut the old ones out.  Is there any way to replace them without removing the whole tire assembly and potentially messing up the seal and ball bearings inside? (Brakes and everything else necessary to normally replace studs has already been removed. The problem is that there isn't enough space  between the opening and the more complicated parts of the tire assembly, and there isn't a groove like there usually is for replacing studs.)

Comment: Are you saying that you don't have enough space because you are not taking the rim off the vehicle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the service manual for the 93 Buick and you have to grind the old studs out and put a small stud in for replacement or remove the hub. You can not install the regular size stud without removing the hub!

Answer (score 2):

Is this on the front or the back? Also, did you try taking the brake rotor off of the hub?

In either case (front or back), you should be able to remove the caliper, brake pads, and rotor off of the hub. When you get down this deep, there should be plenty of room to get the studs out and replace them.

**EDIT:**

[image]
[image]

***IF*** you cannot get the studs out, you'll need to take the hub assembly off from the steering knuckle. To do that, there is the bit nut which is used to keep the drive axle in place on the front (left image). Then there are three bolts which hold it onto the steering knuckle (right image). Be careful when pulling the hub out as you can damage the wheel bearing and would need to replace the hub.

Comment: Brakes and everything else necessary to normally replace studs has already been removed. The problem is that there isn't enough space between the opening and the more complicated parts of the tire assembly, and there isn't a groove like there usually is for replacing studs. (Also, its the front right tire)

Comment: A picture would really help. The tyre assembly in my mind is the wheel and tyre and must be off the car if you have removed the brakes already?

Comment: @CeaseofMorality - Please see edit.

Comment: I'll try to add a picture when I get back from work. In any case I would reaaally rather not remove the hub assembly. I don't want to damage anything that would cost a fortune to fix later. Are there any shorter studs on the market that I could use or any other solution?

Comment: @CeaseofMorality - Realistically I think you are missing something. With the design of those hubs, you should be able to replace the studs after removing the brakes with the hubs still on the car. GM designers were smart enough to deal with this (other manufacturers didn't seem so smart). Like Mauro said I think a picture of your hub on the car would be of great assistance in helping you.